# Deleting UITableViewCell causing crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I know there's a number of posts on this subject and I've been through most of them but I still can't solve an issue I'm having when deleting a tableViewCell causing my app to crash with the follow error:

`Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:]
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})'`

I explicitly set the height of my rows using

`tableView.rowHeight = 140`

My code for the delete is as follows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        let object = self.datastore[indexPath.row]

        do {
            try self.realm?.write {
                self.realm?.delete(object)

                    self.datastore.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            }

        } catch let error {

        }
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

This does delete the item correctly from the dataStore. I've tried a number of different solutions here such as calling the delete on the mainThread, reloading the whole dataSource etc. but it still crashes.

My `numberOfRowsInSection` method gets called and is return the correct number of rows after the deletion so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Adding a general exception breakpoint though I think it's crashing here

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell {
        cell.image.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
    }
}
```

kf here is the kingfisher library as I want to cancel an image download if the cell is removed

What I have noticed is that if I use

```
  `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")`
```

instead of 
      `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)`

This doesn't crash, so that might be my solution, but I'm eager to understand what's wrong here. I understand that the 'forIndexPath' method should always return a cell but in this instance is crashing because of a nil.

I have the same deletion code in another viewController that doesn't rely on the didEndDisplaying:Cell method and this doesn't crash

Comment: try to change priority :  
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                    self.datastore.remove(at: indexPath.row)

Comment: That won't work as you have to edit your datasource before performing deletions otherwise there's an incorrect count causing an invalid update exception  edit ** In fact I've just confirmed this won't work

Comment: in which line your code stopped ?

Comment: if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell in the didEndDisplaying cell method as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: change this line in didEndDisplaying. you need to get existing cell,   let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

Comment: Ah of course! So obvious now, I had this issue previously and totally forgot about it!

Comment: is working now ?

Comment: Yes in fact, the method gives me a reference to the cell so it was even simpler as:

if let cell = cell as? MyCellClass {
     //do stuff
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line in didEndDisplaying. you need to get existing cell.

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.

Make sure that when you're deleting your cell, your goal is not to remove the entire section. My tableView is built on a varying length of sections instead of rows.

I found that by replacing

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic
```

with:

```
tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
```

I was able to get fix the bug. **Make sure you want to delete the entire section however before you implement this change!**

Hope this helps, cheers :)